# Why will the CSS/Javascript and HTML only pass some properties, but not all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have downloaded source code for a hidden search bar, that when clicked, reveals a text input bar.

I have copied this html into my `homepage.html`:

```
<div id="reserveButtonOuter">
  <button id="reserveButton">Reserve a Table</button>
</div>

<div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
  <form>
    <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Enter your search term..." type="search" value="" name="search" id="search">
    <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="">
    <span class="sb-icon-search"></span>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is connected to my `HomePage.js` file, in which I have the code below:

```
;( function( window ) {

    function UISearch( el, options ) {  
      this.el = el;
      this.inputEl = el.querySelector( 'form > input.sb-search-input' );
      this._initEvents();
    }

    UISearch.prototype = {
      _initEvents : function() {
        var self = this,
          initSearchFn = function( ev ) {
            if( !classie.has( self.el, 'sb-search-open' ) ) { // open it
              ev.preventDefault();
              self.open();
            }
            else if( classie.has( self.el, 'sb-search-open' ) && /^\s*$/.test( self.inputEl.value ) ) { // close it
              self.close();
            }
          }

        this.el.addEventListener( 'click', initSearchFn );
        this.inputEl.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) { ev.stopPropagation(); });
      },
      open : function() {
        classie.add( this.el, 'sb-search-open' );
      },
      close : function() {
        classie.remove( this.el, 'sb-search-open' );
      }
    }
```

This is only a small part of the code, as it is several hundred lines.
The .css file is linked to my page fine as it is working for my other elements. The search bar is rendering as nothing more than an orange square, which when clicked shows no errors on the console. Im not sure what that means for the Javascript?

Any advice would be great, thanks!

Comment: An advise would be to find a way to narrow your question to a more specific problem. Something that could be answered in a couple lines...  Reading your question, I finally understand that the plugin (unknown for us since you don't even name it) is not rendering correctly. Have you followed the plugin installation instructions? Did you made some changes to it? Before blaming some languages features, you have to demonstrate that you know what you're doing... And your question, as it is now, isn't making it.

Answer (score 0):

My advice for you is to check in the developer tools what css is enforced on the element.
Maybe you are loading some values with higher priorities, or maybe your selectors are not correct, or you might have js exception thrown, before the css loading..

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the amount of code involved is too big to post here, but I have created this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/smvsrLa3/

For some reason they are stacking up on each other, I'm not sure why because in the demo the tabs are horizontal, and when clicked they respond to the click, unlike the demo that was given. 

Any idea what could be causing this?